# Use Websockets to control a browser window

Tags: javascript, websocket

Some CLI apps in *nix use a $BROWSER environment variable, so that it can call `$BROWSER http://www.unix.com`

I'm just looking for an executable to set as `$BROWSER` that actually controls a remote arbitrary HTML5 browser window via Websockets.

Writing the executable would be easy -- all I have to do is connect via websockets and send some messages.

Question:
But what about the browser side? Is there a JS library that will let me control the browser (at least set its `window.location`) via Websockets?

Answer (score 0):

You can use sock.js to communicate with the server, it supports many server technologies:
https://github.com/sockjs/sockjs-client

Then I would suggest you don't use window.location as it would refresh the page, which defeats the points of websockets.

You can use something like angularjs to update the view when the change event is fired.

index.html

```
<div ng-view></div>
<script src="http://cdn.sockjs.org/sockjs-0.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.8/angular.min.js">
<script src="js/App.js"></script>
```

Child.js

```
angular.module('App', [])

    .controller('AppCtrl', function ($scope) {
        var sock = new SockJS('http://localhost:9999/chat');

        $scope.messages = [];
        $scope.sendMessage = function () {
            sock.send($scope.messageText);
            $scope.messageText = "";
        };

        sock.onmessage = function (e) {
            $scope.messages.push(e.data);
            $scope.$apply();
        };
    });
```

I've created an example of a nodejs server using sockjs to update the view using angularjs:
https://github.com/kmturley/angular-websockets